# Smooth performance on fragment shared element transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I have this Activity with FrameLayout where i load two fragment with a shared element, the animation work, but is very slow and not smooth. Please help me make this transition be more smooth.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Fragment splashFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, splashFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animate();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    public void Animate() {
        Fragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Fade exitFade = new Fade();
        exitFade.setDuration(300);
        splashFragment.setExitTransition(exitFade);

        TransitionSet enterTransitionSet = new TransitionSet();
        enterTransitionSet.addTransition(TransitionInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
        enterTransitionSet.setDuration(1000);
        enterTransitionSet.setStartDelay(300);
        loginFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(enterTransitionSet);

        Fade enterFade = new Fade();
        enterFade.setStartDelay(1300);
        enterFade.setDuration(300);
        loginFragment.setEnterTransition(enterFade);

        View logo = ((SplashFragment) splashFragment).logo;
        fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(logo, logo.getTransitionName());
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, loginFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I have this Activity with FrameLayout where i load two fragment with a shared element, the animation work, but is very slow and not smooth. Please help me make this transition be more smooth.

I tried use hardwareacceleration on manifest, but not working.

I know that all animations on application not is smooth.